# Second monitor disabled after reboot in 18.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, 18.10

I recently upgraded from 18.04 and now the second monitor is disabled every time I reboot. It seems it is struggling holding the config or something between boots, but as long as I suspend/resume (which I normally do), everything is fine.

This means I have to go into gnome settings > display and re-enable it after logging in.

Anyone else having similar issues and have a workaround/fix?

Comment: There shouldn't be that many differences between 18.04 and 18.10, unlike when coming from for example 16.04. Do you have a discrete graphics card?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia exactly what I thought. And yes you are right about the graphics. According to the Ubuntu about page I have `Intel® HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2)`

Comment: Intel graphics drivers are installed by default and should work. I never had an issue with Intel.